# Minified Webpack JS Bundle causing Unexpected Token on Safari

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a minified, bundled JS file using Webpack. The file is working on modern browsers, but when I get to Safari 12.1.2, it causes this error:

```
Unexpected token '='. Expected an opening '(' before a method's parameter list.
```

Here's the minified bit of code, where the error is being thrown at line 1:0

```
(()=>{"use strict";class e{constructor(){this.metabox=document.querySelector("#polarity-metabox") ... // Code continues
```

I'm new to Webpack, and this is my first project using it - is there anything in Webpack's settings I can use to fix it? How can I fix this error?

### Webpack Config:

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  
  entry: {
    theme: __dirname + "/assets/js/modules-theme/index.js",
    product: __dirname + "/assets/js/modules-product/index.js",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundled.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/js/"),
  },
  mode: "production",
  watch: true,
};
```

Comment: Just did - it's really simple with no plugins.

Comment: You could try to pass a browserlist or `'es5'` to the [`target` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/)